# Azure CosmosDb + EF Core: Can't use embedded collections inside owned properties?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

We're using Cosmos db with EF Core.

We have a model like this:

```
class Root 
{
   public Child? Child { get; set; }
}

class Child 
{
   public List<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; }
}
```

Configured as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Root>().OwnsOne(x => x.Child);
```

However, I can't figure out how to configure the `GrandChildren` array within the owned property `Child`.

Without any configuration, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Child.GrandChildren' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

After attempting to add configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasMany(x => x.GrandChildren);
```

Now I face a different error:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Stack Trace: 
> InternalEntityTypeBuilder.CreateForeignKey(InternalEntityTypeBuilder
> principalEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, Key principalKey, String propertyBaseName, Nullable`1 required,
> ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
> InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType,
> Nullable`1 navigationToTarget, Nullable`1 inverseNavigation,
> Nullable`1 setTargetAsPrincipal, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 required)
> InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(TypeIdentity& targetEntityType,
> MemberIdentity& navigation, Nullable`1 inverse, ConfigurationSource configurationSource) InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(TypeIdentity& typeIdentity, MemberIdentity navigation, ConfigurationSource configurationSource) OwnedNavigationBuilder`2.OwnsManyBuilder[TNewRelatedEntity](TypeIdentity
> ownedType, MemberIdentity navigation)
> OwnedNavigationBuilder`2.OwnsMany[TNewDependentEntity](Expression`1
> navigationExpression)
> <>c.b__13_4(OwnedNavigationBuilder`2 cb) line 39 EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsOne[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression, Action`1 buildAction)
> ConfigurationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder
> modelBuilder) line 32 ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder
> modelBuilder, DbContext context)

Apparently this is a limitation of EF Core provider for cosmosdb that owned items cannot have owned properties of their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to configure the `GrandChildren` array within the owned property `Child`.

I tried with the below code which stores `GrandChildren` array within the owned property `Child`.

```cs
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Root> Roots {get; set;}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var endpoint = "*****";
        var key = "******";
        var databaseName = "nestedDb";

        optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(endpoint, key, databaseName);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Root>().OwnsOne(x => x.Child, cb =>
        {
            cb.OwnsMany(c => c.GrandChildren);
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new YourDbContext())
        {
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var grandChild1 = new GrandChild { Id = 1, Name = "Pavan", Age = 25 };
            var grandChild2 = new GrandChild { Id = 2, Name = "Balaji", Age = 20 };

            var child = new Child
            {
                GrandChildren = new List<GrandChild> { grandChild1, grandChild2 }
            };

            var root = new Root
            {
                Child = child
            };

            dbContext.Roots.Add(root);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Root and related entities saved to Cosmos DB.");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

**Explanation:**

- Initially define the Entities such as **Root**, **Child** and **GrandChild**.
- `YourDbContext` class derives from `DbContext`, which Entity Framework Core provides for interacting with databases.
- The `Roots` property is a `DbSet` that represents the database's collection of Root entities.
- `OnConfiguring` and `OnModelCreating` configures `connection` details and relationship between `Root`, `Child`, and `GrandChild` respectively.
- The two `GrandChild` entities are added to the collection of `GrandChildren` of a Child entity.
- The Child entity is allocated to the Child property of the Root object.
- The data is saved to the Cosmos DB database by using the dbContext.SaveChanges() function.
- The `OwnsOne` and `OwnsMany` methods in the `OnModelCreating` method assist in defining the ownership connections between entities. One Child belongs to The Root, and that Child belongs to numerous `GrandChild` entities.
- For further please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).